# Is it possible to record the sound of both mic and speaker during a call in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop an application to record calls both side(mic and speaker). I was using "media recorder" in android before but the issue was that the app was not compatible in lots of the devices.

So, I am trying to capture the sound from both mic and speaker and will merge in one audio file.

Comment: Do you actually mean the frequency (like in Hertz) or do you mean "channel" or simply "sound"?

Comment: I mean to sound. Wich, we can listen.